# JavaScript Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

народ!
Вот уже как 3-4 дня я сижу и учу JS, и в голову пришла идея создать свой слайдер картинок.
*Конечно, я понимаю, что на YouTube уже есть готовые решения, но эти решения выглядят очень глупо!*

**В общем, мне надо сделать так, что при клике на кнопку, картинка менялась.
Хочется сделать так, чтобы картинка просто меняла свой номер в массиве.**
Проще думаю кинуть кусок кода.
*Приму любой вариант решения!*

```js
const sliderPrev = document.querySelector(".slider-prev");
const sliderNext = document.querySelector(".slider-next");

sliderNext.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
sliderPrev.addEventListener("click", prevSlide);

function nextSlide(event) {
 const sliderIMG = document.querySelectorAll("img");
 console.log("next")
}

function prevSlide(event) {
 const sliderIMG = document.querySelectorAll("img");
 console.log("prev")
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ffbe76;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider-items {
 border: 3px solid #fafafa;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-nav{
 margin-top: 20px;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

button {
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}
button:hover{
 background-color: #cccccc;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}

img {
    max-width: 900px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-items">
      <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="Горы 1">
      <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="Горы 2">
      <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="Горы 3">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-nav">
      <button class="slider-prev">Prev</button>
      <button class="slider-next">Next</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет о простом переключении картинки, без самого эффекта "пролистывания", я бы предложил такой вариант:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/yuo9rvsb/)

```js
(function(){
//Все картинки сохраняем в массиве
let img = [
  'https://i.gyazo.com/34a5722e08245a0904418ea46a041457.png', // получить через img[0]
  'https://gyazo.com/b37e3ee7fdcb71d36f55febf7a6193fd.png', // img[1]
  'https://gyazo.com/a7eb9830c197e1f3a4bc2f7b18bf78b8.png' // img[2]
];

const slide = document.getElementById('slide');
let i = 0;//создаем переменную = 0;

document.getElementById('slider-next').addEventListener('click',function(){
  //При каждом клике увеличиваем число на 1
  i++;
  //Если оно оказывается равным кол-ву картинок (в данном случае 3),
  // возвращаем i к исходному значению 0
  if ( i == img.length ) { i = 0; } // элемента img[3] не существует.
  //меняем src по номеру i, вытаскивая элемент из массива.
  slide.src = img[i];
});

document.getElementById('slider-prev').addEventListener('click',function(){
  i--;
  if ( i < 0 ) { i = (img.length - 1); }
  slide.src = img[i];
});

})();
```

```css
#slide {width: 160px; height: 160px;}
```

```html
<img id="slide" src="https://i.gyazo.com/34a5722e08245a0904418ea46a041457.png">
<br>
<button id="slider-prev">Prev</button>
<button id="slider-next">Next</button>
```

Потому что... зачем заморачиваться с переключением HTML-элементов, если можно взять один и переключать его значение...

Если убрать комменты, код покажется не таким уж большим))

P.s. прикрутил бы к самой картинке ту же функцию, что и у Next... чтобы и при клике на картинку - сразу переключало.

Comment: Да, спасибо! Это то что мне нужно, мне важно понять суть алгоритма. Так сказать, руку набиваю. Ещё раз спасибо! <3

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.slider-prev').on('click', function(){
  
  if($('.slider-items img.active').prev().is('img'))
    $('.slider-items img.active').removeClass('active').prev('img').addClass('active');
  
});

$('.slider-next').on('click', function(){
  
  if($('.slider-items img.active').next().is('img'))
    $('.slider-items img.active').removeClass('active').next('img').addClass('active');
  
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ffbe76;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider-items {
   border: 3px solid #fafafa;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slider-nav{
 margin-top: 20px;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

button {
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}
button:hover{
 background-color: #cccccc;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}

img {
    max-width: 900px;
    background-size: cover;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
img.active {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
   <div class="slider-items">
    <img class="active" src="https://www.loudwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/big-dark-mountain-hd-wallpaper-1920x1280p.jpg">
    <img src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/765/765656.jpg">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530814394340-02d8010713d8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80">
   </div>
   <div class="slider-nav">
    <button class="slider-prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="slider-next">Next</button>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Я оставил в css коде не **display: none;** а **visibility**, чтобы вы могли добавить эффект **opacity**, **transform (rotate, scale, translate)** . В случае с **display: none;** вам бы не удалось создать анимацию появления.